# I made this date of birth program can I make it more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x

Program only excepts the date of birth if entered correctly. Is there any other efficient way?

```
while True:
user_input = input("Enter your date of birth in the following format DD/MM/YYYY: ")
DOB = user_input.split("/")
if len(DOB) == 3:
    day = DOB[0]
    month = DOB[1]
    year = DOB[2]
    try:
        if int(day) in range(1,32) and int(month) in range(1,13) and int(year) in range(1900,2018):
            print ("Thanks")
            break
        else:
            continue
    except:
        print ("Try again")

else:
    print ("Try again")
```

Comment: it depends what you mean by "efficient"

Comment: Efficiency will never be a concern for this script since you're waiting for user input, which will take the longest. Your script will accept invalid dates such as Feb 30th. Consider using https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: Are you looking to clean up the code (i.e. less lines of code/simpler solution) or make it faster?